# How to write count statement in Apache IoTDB to check the number of query records?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to check the number of records returned as query results in Apache IoTDB. I tried to use `count(*)` command, but multiple values are returned instead of one total value of the number of results I needed. I want to know how should I write the query statement to check the number of records in IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count_time(*)` to query the number of timestamps in the result set of Apache IoTDB, and this should be the same as the number of records you want. When you only use `count(*)`, it will automatically count all the fields included in the time series, which will be separately present in the query result. That's why you got multiple values instead of a number.